# How to pass table alias to subsubquery in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, oracle10g, scope, correlated-subquery

I've been struggling with `SQL` for a while now. I have to build a query to return a second highest id from a table. Sounds simple, especially if you've found [that link](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_select_the_top_n_rows_from_a_table).

But I have a bit more complicated query:

```
SELECT 
  p.column1,
  p.column2,
  p.column3,
  p.column4,
  (
    SELECT 
      p.column1 
    FROM 
      p_table p
    WHERE 
      p.column2 = (
        SELECT
          id
        FROM (
          SELECT 
            id,
            RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) rank_id
          FROM 
            other_table 
          WHERE 
            field = p.column3
        )
        WHERE
          rank_id = 2
      )
    ) AS sth
FROM ...
```

Oracle says [ORA-00904: Unknown identifier](http://ora-00904.ora-code.com/) at `p.column3`.
I understand why it says so - it doesn't recognize `p` as table name alias.

Is it possible to pass it to nested query?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a column from a query to a nested query of a nested query.

I think this could do the same job:

```
    SELECT 
      p.column1,
      p.column2,
      p.column3,
      p.column4,
      (
        SELECT 
          p.column1 
        FROM 
          p_table p
        WHERE 
          (p.column2, 2) = (SELECT id,
                                   RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) rank_id
                              FROM 
                                    other_table 
                             WHERE 
                                    field = p.column3
                             )

        ) AS sth
    FROM
```